# DropDownList selected value property is not getting copied 

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have HTML table in which user make GRUD operations. But everyone knows that **jQuery** serialize method works only with forms. So I am cloning current row to hidden form and then serialize it and posting data to server. But I have problem with DropDownList.

So when I am cloning current row all goes well except the selected value of DropDownList. I have wrote little **JavaScript** code to solve it. After cloning I wrote it

```
$('#clonedForm select#ConsumptionType').val($("#dataTable tbody tr:first select#ConsumptionType").val());
```

It solved my problem. But I want to know where is problem. Simple textbox value is getting copied, but why is dropdownlist not?

I am using jQuery 1.1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [ticket about this issue](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1294).